# Is it true that using redux with react will eliminate the need of react's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In react-redux library, there is almost only one API, `connect()`, and its only purpose is to bind "redux-things" to react's props. That's fine, but as far as I could see, the application state is handled with redux's state. I find no use of react's state anymore, since, a component could be rendered using props alone and mutate its state (via redux's state) using actions.

Am I correct ?

Comment: No it's not entirely correct: not every state must reside in a global application state. There still are uses for component internal states. Eg: when a dropdown component is expanded - it is its internal state.

Comment: Could you please provide me a source I can read further about "breaking point" where this kinda state should be placed in app's state and this shouldn't. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I can, it's vague and just a preference. The rule I personally use is "If it can be rendered in html - it *most likely* belongs to the global state; if it cannot - it definitely is a local state"

Comment: A rule of thumb I often use is: how many components will care about this state? If it's just this one — not even other instances will use it — then local state is fine. (e.g., current textbox value, open/close state of dropdowns, etc). If the state will affect the application as a whole, or describes some *application domain concept*, then it's probably global app state.

Comment: If you look at dekujs.github.io/deku/ they have got rid of local state management in favour of redux. You can still use unmanaged local state but there's no magic to it (i.e. throttled setState re-rendering the component).

Comment: The advantage of using global, separated state apart from leading to easier to manage "app flow"/architecture, is that re-rendering optimisations can be made for your components (*memoization*). React has some optimisations for pure functional components already and this could get faster. A component which is purely receiving props is easier to "reason about".

Comment: However I'm not sure if it makes sense to keep all state globally - it requires more boilerplate and you might think "this component only ever needs to know about this" - sometimes you might just think that `this.setState({ toggle: true })` is a heck of a lot simpler to read and write than creating some action constants, an action, and a reducer handler and dispatching to it.

Comment: @DominicTobias Good point! I am a pro-global state, but indeed it's a huge boilerplate.